# Hide HTML tags with Jsoup in Android

Tags: android, parsing, webview, jsoup

I am working with an Android application. I want must only load items from site and hide some tags (header, footer, search panel ). I have used Webview and `Jsoup` for this. All working fine. But when I click some item, in the new page will open header/ footer again. How to I can hide header and footer using this code ?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

WebView webview;
String url="http://hut.az/";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    webview= (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);



    new MyAsynTask().execute();

}

private class MyAsynTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Document> {
    @Override
    protected Document doInBackground(Void... voids) {

        Document document = null;

        try {
            document= Jsoup.connect(url).get();
            document.getElementsByClass("header1").remove();
            document.getElementsByClass("topbar clearfix").remove();
            document.getElementsByClass("mapandslider").remove();
            document.getElementsByClass("footer1").remove();
            document.getElementsByClass("copyright").remove();


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
   return document ;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Document document) {
        super.onPostExecute(document);

        webview.loadDataWithBaseURL(url,document.toString(),"text/html","utf-8","");
        webview.getSettings().setCacheMode( WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK );
        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            private WebView view;
            private WebResourceRequest request;

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
                this.view = view;
                this.request = request;
                view.loadUrl(url);

                return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, request);
            }



        });

    }
}
}
```

When opens app:

[image: When opens app]

When I click any item, header and footer shows again
[image: When I click any item, header and footer shows again]

Answer (score 1):

It is because you open a whole new page in `Webview` then you haven't remove tags in that new webpage, what you have to do is change your code into

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    WebView webview;
    String url="http://hut.az/";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webview= (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webview.getSettings().setCacheMode( WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK );
        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

                new MyAsynTask().execute(url);
                return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
            }

        });

        new MyAsynTask().execute(this.url);

    }

    private class MyAsynTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Document> {
        @Override
        protected Document doInBackground(String... urls) {

            Document document = null;
            try {

                document= Jsoup.connect(urls[0]).get();
                document.getElementsByClass("header1").remove();
                document.getElementsByClass("topbar clearfix").remove();
                document.getElementsByClass("mapandslider").remove();
                document.getElementsByClass("footer1").remove();
                document.getElementsByClass("copyright").remove();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return document;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Document document) {
            super.onPostExecute(document);
            webview.loadDataWithBaseURL(url,document.toString(),"text/html","utf-8","");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks bro, worked !)
But have a problem. When opens new page, header hides after open site. How to solve this ?

Comment: Then you should remove document.getElementsByClass("header1").remove();